# HTML onchange event sometimes fires twice on input checkbox element

Tags: javascript, html

This happens to me in Chrome 79.0.

CodePen replicating the issue:
https://codepen.io/puckowski/pen/eYmEbVz

I have a basic `input` element which looks like:
`<input type="checkbox">`

In JavaScript, I define an `onchange` property like so:

```
let eventObj = {
    onchange: function() { console.log('event fired'); }
}
```

I then set my `input` element's `onchange` property like so:

```
for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(eventObj)) {
    vType = typeof v;

    if (vType === 'function') {
        inputElem[k] = v; // inputElem is the correct element in the document and not undefined
    }
}
```

Effectively, `inputElem` is defined by:

```
inputElem = document.getElementById('foo');
```

The `onchange` event is bound only once per the method above.

When I click on the checkbox, sometimes the `onchange` event fires once, sometimes it fires twice.

This doesn't seem to be an event bubbling issue. If I change the bound function to the following:

```
function(evt) { console.log('event fired'); evt.stopPropagation(); }
```

The `onchange` event will still fire twice occasionally.

Any ideas as to what is going on? Is this perhaps a element focus issue?

Comment: Can you show us how you assigned `inputElem`?

Comment: Updated question to include information about ```inputElem```. The definition is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked fine for me:

```
function(evt) { 
  console.log('event fired'); 
  evt.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
}
```